# Demons are summoned by doing math

Tags: story-identification, laundry-files

I recall once reading a series of short stories where any sort of calculation would summon demons or perform other magic. The main character was an investigator of some sort, and his boss was (secretly) a summoned and geased demon. 
What universe did this take place in?

Comment: *Any* sort of calculation? Can you give us an example, a scene, a bit of plot? Roughly how long ago did you read it, and in what language? Was it a book, a magazine series or online? Were people carrying swords? Riding steam-driven, demon-fired locomotives? Wearing fedoras and trenchcoats? Was the fantasy tinged with math-science-fiction? Comedy? Horror? Was it Lovecraftian? Zelaznian? Hofstaderian? Did it mention Alan Turing or Kurt Gödel?

Comment: See, this is why I refused to do Maths homework in school. Let the smart kids get eaten by demons.

Comment: @Beta: I'd elaborate If I hadn't already gotten the answer I was looking for. Also, these were really the only details I remembered, aside from the fact it was written in English. Also, yes, *any* sort of calculation. Doing lots of math in your head is a good way to get your brain eaten.

Comment: I always knew that math was evil

Comment: Ah @Robert! You beat me to that one!!

Comment: "geased"? typo?

Comment: A "geas" is a type of magic spell, typically a spell of forbidding or compelling.

Comment: @Dan Well, strictly speaking it's not _any_ sort of calculation: Stross makes it quite clear that it's only some very complex maths, like cryptographic, financial and scientific modeling, things along those lines, which suddenly can open portals. Including inside your brain. ;)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It may be Charles Stross' [*Laundry Files*](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=laundry%20files%20series) series. The series, which consists of novels, short-stories and novellas, is based on the very Lovecraftian idea of crossing magic and mathematics. The main character, Bob Howard, is an agent of a secret British agency that is charged with investigating and controlling the magical results of certain higher mathematical functions. There are hints in the earlier stories that Bob's boss is something other than strictly human. The novel *The Fuller Memorandum* goes into more detail on his boss' nature.

Comment: Advisory: The earlier stories in the _Laundry Files_ are fairly light-hearted. Stross has warned us that as the date of the Old Ones return approaches, the stories are going to become considerably darker. His Hugo-winning novella _Equoid_ is arguably the start of that trend; it's significantly disturbing, and the copy on tor.com carries a quite justified warning that it "contains scenes and situations some readers will find upsetting and/or repellent." I like Stross's writing, and I like what he has done with the Laundry, but not all readers will want to follow where he's going with it.

Comment: @keshlam Indeed, and good on him for doing so. You can only carry the Dilbertesque aspects so far when the storyline is moving towards actual Living Envy The Dead Except There Will Be No Dead Just Legions Of Possessed Corpses Mentally Screaming In Eternal Agony territory. As an equestrian myself, Equoid was a tough one. I've never looked at the inevitable gaggle of horsie girls I see all time, in the same way. >.<